# Определение шаблонной переменной без inline

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть заголовочный файл:

```
// a.hpp

template<typename T>
int a;
```

И два сырца:

```
// a.cpp

#include "a.hpp"

int main() {
    std::cout << a<int> << '\n';
}

// b.cpp

#include "a.hpp"

auto&& b = (std::cout << a<int> << '\n');
```

Почему не происходит ошибки двойного определения и программа выводит два нуля? Я не указывал `inline`. В чём будет разница, если я укажу `inline`?

Comment: Читайте http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#13 и следующий пункт (14) тоже

Comment: @Croessmah "В чём будет разница, если я укажу `inline`?"

Comment: Если здесь не скажут, попробуйте на английском SO спросить.

Comment: @ramadan я затрудняюсь сравнивать тепло с мягким. Добавление `inline` сделает шаблон переменной шаблоном inline-переменной. В плане множественного определения это ничего не изменит, если вы об этом.

Comment: @ramadan, определение шаблона, это еще не определение конкретной сущности, а инструкция_  поэтому, если коротко, то inline ничего не даст.

Comment: @Croessmah А в каком-то другом плане изменения будут? `inline` на неконстантных переменных делает что-то, кроме разрешения множественных определений?

Answer (score 2):

Не будет никакой разницы - шаблон (`template`) сам по себе является `inline`, потому у вас все и работает.

Вас же не удивляет, что в такой же ситуации шаблонная функция без всякого `inline` не приводит к ошибке двойного определения?

Comment: Позанудствую: шаблоны не становятся автоматически `inline`, хотя множественные определения для них разрешены.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, и шаблоны и inline определяются в хэдерах, так зачем?

Answer (score 2):

Для шаблонов разрешается нарушение One Definition Rule (правило единственного определения) [basic.def.odr]:

> There can be more than one definition of a
> ...
> — [templated entity](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#13.4),

> [For each such entity and for D itself, the behavior is as if there is a single entity with a single definition](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#14)

Ведёт такой шаблон себя так как будто в программе имеется единственное определение этой сущности.

В свою очередь `inline` говорит следующее [dcl.inline]:

> [An inline function or variable with external or module linkage has the same address in all translation units.](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.inline#6)

`inline` функция или переменная с внешней связностью имеет одинаковый адрес во всех единицах трансляции.

Т.о. добавление `inline` к определению шаблонной переменной ничего не меняет с точки зрения поведения.

Comment: Интересно, что даже на `const` шаблонных переменных `inline` [ничего не меняет](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48041618/2752075). Оказывается на переменных из `<type_traits>` он лишний...